# Spring Integration Headers are not getting injected to Service Activator POJO

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-integration

Spring Integration Headers are not getting injected to Service Activator POJO.This happens only at the time of load testing (with less than 10 tps).
Normal flow its is working as expected.
Spring integration flow is

```
Splitter -> executor channel -> service activator -> aggregator.

SI version 4.1.2.RELEASE
Spring Version 4.1.2.RELEASE
Java version 1.8.0_60

//service activator -Method     
public ProductDetail getProductDetails(final String productID,
            @Header(STATS) final Stats statsType,
            @Header(SKU) final String sku,
            @Header(PRODUCT_LIST) final Collection<String> productList,
            @Header(NO_OF_PRODUCTS) final String size) 

final MessageBuilder<Map<String, Object>> msgBuilder = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(payload);//Map<String, Object> payload
this.addMessageHeaders(msgBuilder, httpHeadersMap, statsType);


private final boolean addMessageHeaders(MessageBuilder<?> msgBuilder,
            final Map<String, String> httpHeadersMap, final Stats statsType) {
        if ((httpHeadersMap != null) && (httpHeadersMap.size() > 0)) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : httpHeadersMap.entrySet()) {
                msgBuilder.setHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        if (statsType != null) {
            msgBuilder.setHeader(STATS, statsType);
        }
        return true;
}
```

> org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: required header not available: STATS
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:48) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$1.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:92) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at xx.run(DelegatingContextRunnable.java:40) ~[xx-core-3.xx.jar:3.24.0.52]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: required header not available: STATS
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]

```
<int:channel id="retrieve-product.in" />
<int:channel id="retrieve-product.out" />
<int:channel id="retrieve-product.err" />
<int:channel id="retrieve-product.splitter.in"/>
<int:channel id="retrieve-product.sa.in">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="testExecutor" failover="false"/>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="retrieve-product.aggregator.in"/>
<int:channel id="retrieve-product.transformer.in"/>

<bean id="retrieveProductsServiceActivatorSupport" class="com.test.eip.serviceactivator.support.RetrieveProductsServiceActivatorSupport" />
<bean id="retrieveProductsServiceActivator" class="com.test.eip.serviceactivator.RetrieveProductsServiceActivator" />
<bean id="retrieveProductsAggregator" class="com.test.eip.aggregator.RetrieveProductsAggregator" />
<bean id="retrieveProductResponseTransformer" class="com.test.eip.transformer.RetrieveProductsResponseTransformer" />
<bean id="productGroupsConfig" class="com.test.support.ProductGroupsConfig" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="ProductMapping.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="payloadSizeBasedReleaseStrategy" class="com.test.eip.aggregator.support.PayloadSizeBasedReleaseStrategy" />
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="productConfigJaxbMarshaller" context-path="com.test.product.config.types" />

<int:gateway id="retrieveProductsGateway" service-interface="com.test.eip.gateway.IProductGateway" error-channel ="retrieve-product.err">
    <int:method name="getProductsResponse" request-channel="retrieve-product.in" reply-channel="retrieve-product.out" />
</int:gateway>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="retrieve-product.in" output-channel="retrieve-product.splitter.in">
    <int:header name="API_NAME" value="retrieve-product" />
</int:header-enricher>
<!-- Input List<String> contain product numbers --> 
<int:splitter id="productListSplitter" input-channel="retrieve-product.splitter.in" 
                output-channel="retrieve-product.sa.in"></int:splitter>
<!-- Retrieve Product Features from USING API -->               
<int:service-activator input-channel="retrieve-product.sa.in"
    ref="retrieveProductsServiceActivator" method="getProductDetails"
    output-channel="retrieve-product.aggregator.in"
    id="retrieve-product-service-activator" />
<!-- Aggregate result from Parallel Call -->
<int:aggregator input-channel="retrieve-product.aggregator.in"
    output-channel="retrieve-product.transformer.in"
    method="aggregateProductDetails" ref="retrieveProductsAggregator"
    release-strategy="payloadSizeBasedReleaseStrategy"
    release-strategy-method="canRelease">
</int:aggregator>

<!-- Generate Service Response-->
<int:transformer id="retrieve-product-ResponseTransformer" method="transform"
        ref="retrieveProductResponseTransformer" input-channel="retrieve-product.transformer.in" output-channel="retrieve-product.out" />

<!-- 
    Listen for error and generate response
 -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="retrieve-product.err"
    ref="testErrorHandler" method="handleExceptions"
    output-channel="retrieve-product.out"
    id="retrieve-product-err-handler" />

public interface IProductGateway {
    public RetrieveProductsResponse getProductsResponse(Message<?> inputMessage);
}

//Service
@Service
public class ProductsService implements IProductsService {
    @Autowired
    private IProductGateway retrieveProductsGateway;

    @Override
    public RetrieveProductsResponse getProductsResponse(
            final RetrieveProductsRequest retrieveProductsRequest,
            final Map<String, String> httpHeadersMap, final Stats statsType) {
        final ProductsReqType products = retrieveProductsRequest.getProducts();
        //populate productList From products
        final Collection<String> productList = new HashSet<>();
        httpHeadersMap.put(SKU, retrieveProductsRequest.getSKU());
        httpHeadersMap.put(NO_OF_PRODUCTS,
                String.valueOf(productList.size()));
        final MessageBuilder<Collection<String>> msgBuilder = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(productList)
                .setHeader(PRODUCT_LIST, new HashSet<>(productList));
        this.addMessageHeaders(msgBuilder, httpHeadersMap, statsType);
        final Message<Collection<String>> inMsg = msgBuilder.build();
        LOG.debug("retrieveProductsGateway:: {}", this.retrieveProductsGateway);
        final RetrieveProductsResponse retrieveProductsResponse = this.retrieveProductsGateway
                .getProductsResponse(inMsg);
        return retrieveProductsResponse;
    }
}

//Jersey Filter is creating Stats setting it to requestContext( javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter)
/* Request Filter Creating and setting statsType 
*/
@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    LOG.debug("filter(requestContext)::Entry");
    final Stats statsType = STATS_OBJ_FACTORY.createStats();
    final MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
    statsType.setBegin(DT_FACTORY.newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar()));
    requestContext.setProperty(STATS, statsType);
    LOG.debug("filter(requestContext)::Exit");
}

//Resource Method taking statsType and passing to ProductsService
/*javax.ws.rs.core.Context*/
@POST
@Path("retrieve-product")
@Produces(MyMediaType.PD_XML_MEDIA_TYPE)
@Consumes(MyMediaType.PD_XML_MEDIA_TYPE)
public Response getProducts(RetrieveProductsRequest retrieveProductsRequest,
        @Context final ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
        @Context final HttpHeaders headers) {
    LOG.debug("getProducts::Entry");
    final Stats statsType = (Stats) containerRequestContext
            .getProperty(STATS);
    final Map<String, String> httpHeadersMap = ResourceHelper
            .getHttpHeadersAsMap(headers);
    final RetrieveProductsResponse retrieveProductsResponse = this.productsService
            .getProductsResponse(retrieveProductsRequest, httpHeadersMap, statsType);
    LOG.debug("getProducts::Exit");
    return Response.ok(retrieveProductsResponse).build();
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> required header not available: STATS

Simply means that whatever is upstream that creates the message is not populating the headers; you need to show all your configuration (and possibly code). DEBUG logging and following the messages will generally help debugging such conditions.

A common mistake is a lack of thread-safety - such as in your splitter.

Comment: Hi Gray, I have updated trimmed version of integration Context XML.Normal case its working which means STATS header is present in Message .This error happens during Load test.

Comment: Well it's clearly not present in your load test case; you didn't show any code or configuration that populates that header. As I said, turning on DEBUG logging will show you the problem.

Comment: It's in my initial post method name addMessageHeaders even though I am doing null check statsType object never be null

Comment: Huh? That's called from `getProductDetails()`; the problem is upstream of that, `@Header(STATS) final Stats statsType` means the incoming message MUST have the header already (you can set `required = false` on `@Headers` to make it optional). You need to run with DEBUG logging so you can examine the message(s) arriving at the service activator.

Comment: This is a web service based on Jersey.resource is passing Jaxb to service layer (pojo annotated with Service spring annotation).which is creating spring integration message using above mentioned methods and invoking SI gateway (IProductGateway) .getProductDetails();  is service activator method which is annotated with Header annotation.Here I am getting header not present exception.Are you seeing any issues with given integration flow.Please see getProductDetails method signature. Do you see any issues with that? Thanks

Comment: Yes, as I said, if the incoming message doesn't have one or more of those headers, you will get the error you are seeing. You also need to annotate `getProductsResponse()` with headers if you are expecting the gateway to populate those headers. Perhaps you should edit your question to show the interface and the calling code.

Comment: Hi Gary I Have updated Question with more Details.Mean time I will add more logging and will change method signature to accept Headers (@Headers final Map<String, Object> msgHeaders) than header and add some validations for headers

Comment: Thanks Gary .I am not seeing any issues when testing SI flows in isolation.So as you suggested this maybe an issue with upstream layers.Thanks a lot.